# Good book for understanding the basics of SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, learning, books

One of my friends just got a MOSS 2007 project. But he doesn't know anything about it. So he asked me to recommend a book which will be very good for understanding the basics of SharePoint in a minimum time as he has a very little time to get all the basic concepts. So please I request to all, recommend a good book for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend doesn't know anything at all about SharePoint and is jumping into this, you may want to check out the SharePoint Shepherd's Guide for End Users by Robert Bogue - [http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-Shepherds-Guide-End-Users/dp/0615194494/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1276899050&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615194494)

It will take them through the basics. I also love Dux's book that is mentioned above, it is excellent for Project Management specific use.

Comment: There are many good SharePoint books, but I cannot say enough good things about Robert Bogue's Guide for End Users.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really mention what your friend will be doing.  If it has anything to do with implementing, customizing, or developing solutions for the platform then I would highly recommend [Professional SharePoint 2007 Development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SharePoint-2007-Development.productCd-0470117567.html) which provides a great overview of the architecture and how all of the pieces fit together.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Sharepoint for Project Management by Dux Raymond Sy:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520151

Or Seamless Teamwork by Michael Sampson:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/mikeg/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1489

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading Microsoft's Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0

this book is the best book for sharepoint beginners